# Use different firebase service account in development and production

Tags: android, django, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

We are using firebase python admin sdk in our django app. (This is used for the phone auth backend verification).

The sdk is authenticated using serviceAccountKey.json file.

What is the best practice to use this in production and development environments? 
It will be good to have a separation So that This file can be safely git ignored.

Comment: What if you get the Admin SDK to load credentials from the environment? You can set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to point to a locally installed service account JSON file, and initialize Admin SDK without any explicit credentials ([more details here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/firebase-separating-configuration-from-code-in-admin-sdk-d2bcd2e87de6)). This will work as long as you're not trying to mint custom JWT tokens from the Admin SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store path to `serviceAccountKey.json` in your env and add this to git ignore. 
Use a different firebase project if DEBUG is `True`